# Recurring payments & Paypal Recurring profiles

Tags: 7, ubercart

I have a couple questions.

First - I have another site - Magento-based - that I'm currently using to handle a membership site. I'm trying to convert it to Drupal 7, and I've got it all configured and ready to go. However, when I get a new subscriber it's coming through as a PURCHASE and not a subscription. I've got each product set up with a recurring fee under "features" and it's set to be monthly. Here is the text from the feature:

"Recurring fee - When [SKU] of this product is purchased, add a fee for $15.00 charged first after 1 months and every 1 months after that unlimited times."

I used the basic set up steps in this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vd6Y4f4TnnU

I'm not sure what's going to happen here. I'm not seeing a recurring profile in Paypal like I did with Magento. Can someone help me understand the progression and workflow here?

BTW - I'm using D7 and Ubercart 7.x-3.1

Second - I need to know what is the mechanism that makes the recurrence charge fire. I've been testing, and the monthly renewal/recharge date has come and gone, but there was no charge made to the account. I know that the payment gateway works, because I've tested that a few times, it's just that the recurring charges are not happening and I don't even know where to begin to look, because so far as I can tell, as noted above, things are set up to charge monthly and recharge monthly.

My setup is virtually identical to what's described in the video.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Did you ever work it out?

Comment: I did, but I'm honestly cannot remember what I did to get it done. It's been working fine for the longest time . It may have been because I was using a test gateway at the time. I'm sorry, I wish I remembered more.